# Scala: How to count occurrences of unique items in a certain index?

Tags: string, list, scala, loops

I have a list that is formatted like the lists below:

```
List(List(21, Georgetown, Male),List(29, Medford, Male),List(18, Manchester, Male),List(27, Georgetown, Female))
```

And I need to count the occurrences of each unique town name, then return the town name and the amount of times it was counted. But I only want to return the one town that had the most occurences. So if I applied the function to the list above, I would get

```
(Georgetown, 2)
```

I'm coming from Java, so I know how to do this process in a longer way, but I want to utilize some of Scala's built in methods.

Comment: Fixed it. I meant to have the lists nested.

Comment: @ChrisMartin need the most popular unique occurrence of the town, with the count of the occurrences.

Comment: What should the result be if there's a tie for the maximum?

Comment: The `List[List[Any]]` makes for a very poor data model, especially for Scala. It would be so much better if you had a class to represent your elements. `case class Person(age: Int, city: String, gender: String)`. This will result in `List[Person]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> val towns = List(
     |     List(21, "Georgetown", "Male"),
     |     List(29, "Medford", "Male"),
     |     List(18, "Manchester", "Male"),
     |     List(27, "Georgetown", "Female"))
towns: List[List[Any]] = ...

scala> towns.map({ case List(a, b, c) => (b, c) }).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.length).maxBy(_._2)
res0: (Any, Int) = (Georgetown,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty weird structure, but a way to do it would be with:

```
  val items : List[List[Any]] = List(
    List(List(21, "Georgetown", "Male")),
    List(List(29, "Medford", "Male")),
    List(List(18, "Manchester", "Male")),
    List(List(27, "Georgetown", "Female"))).map(_.flatten)

  val results = items.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]()) {
    (acc,item) =>
      val key = item(1).asInstanceOf[String]
      val count = acc.getOrElse(key, 0 )
      acc + (key -> (count + 1))
  }

  println(results)
```

Which produces:

```
Map(Georgetown -> 2, Medford -> 1, Manchester -> 1)
```